# Animate.css shake effect not working every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css

I'm making a Twitch Streamer application, that pulls some data using Twitch API, for a predetermined set of streamers.

I have three buttons to select all/online/offline channels, and I am looking to add the `animated shake` effect to all these buttons.

On my first attempt, I had a simple if/else check in place to make the `shake` work correctly - detect if the `animated shake` class already exists, if so, remove it, and then add it again. Else, just add it.

That didn't work. I found an answer here on SO that said it won't work that way because the `addClass` and `removeClass` occur so fast that the DOM doesn't have time to catch up.

I then used a `queue` with an anonymous function to add the class back after inducing a slight delay after the `removeClass` -

```
if ($(this).hasClass("animated shake")) {
            $(this).removeClass("animated shake").delay(50).queue(
                function() {
                    $(this).addClass("animated shake");
                });
            //$(this).addClass("animated shake");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("animated shake");
        }
```

Now, the shake effect works like 90% of the time, but if you keep switching back and forth between online/offline channels, there will be cases in between where the shake doesn't work.

Here's the app on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Nyxx/full/vKgPwp/).

I'd appreciate any help as to why it doesn't work *every single time*.

Note - The shake effect is on the online/offline buttons only, for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works everytime :-D

```js
function shakeButton($button) {
    console.log('Shaking button')
    $button.removeClass("animated shake");
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        $button.addClass("animated shake");
      },
      25
    );
  }

  $('button').click(function() {
    shakeButton($(this));
  });
```

```html
<!-- Never mind, Just some Dummy html... -->

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Never mind this, Just some Dummy Results</h4>
<h3>Check out the JS instead</h3>
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>
```

I just used setTimeout instead `.delay()` And it worked a treat :-)

Good Job, Your code is nice and well documented :-D A Few things though...

1. In your code... you repeat the same code at three places, Instead you can create a function with that code and call that function everywhere instead ;-) This will make debugging easier.
2. The `if` statement you use is not necessary... Just remove `animate` and `shake` classes every time ( it won't throw any error ;-) ) and add them after some time again, this will make code simpler.

This code is implemented in this snippet...
http://codepen.io/shramee/pen/EyZJjN

Comment: Thanks for looking, and for your feedback :) For your point 1, are you referring to the code for this `animated shake` thing? If so, it's a good idea! Refactoring that didn't occur to me as the code was not working correctly all times. Will try out your version now...

Comment: Yeah, talking about code for `animate shake` :-) Let me know how it works for you... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

can you try something like this?

```
$('.btn').on('click', function()
{
    // Siblings will target other buttons but not the current one
    $(this).addClass('animated shake').siblings().removeClass('animated shake');
});
```

[EDIT] more relevent to your structure:

According to your example structure you can add a class to your buttons wrapper like `.btnWrapper` for convenience and do:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function()
{
    var clicked = $(this);
    clicked.addClass('animated shake').parents('.btnWrapper').siblings().find('.shake').removeClass('animated shake');
})
```